# htmlHelper.Label and jquery Validation

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I am trying to do some jQuery validation.  I am having a hard time getting a label into my project...

The Label will part of a jQuery UI Dialog, and whenever I have that label in my assignment jQuery UI dialog wont lode the div. I am a little confounded...

```
    %><%=Html.Label("",row)%><%
```

Validate function...

```
     $("#temp1").validate({
        rules: {
            HospitalFinNumber: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            },
            AdminDate: { requried: true }
        }
    });
```

Boy howdy am I confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because the `for` attribute on the label within the generated HTML is not valid; note your casing. You need to explicitly specify this via the overloaded [Html.Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg537983%28v=VS.99%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks for the help a month later.  But I simple used Response.Write("<label for...>").  Not to be sarcastic :-)